# apt-get fails to install and remove package

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia, apt, apt-get, dpkg

I wanted to install cuda on my ubuntu 18.04, and also install nvidia-driver-450. but sth was wrong. when I restart my laptop, gui did'nt load and a command line appear. first i run `sudo apt-get install -f` . but it raise error

```
Errors where encountered while proccessing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-gl-450_450.57-0ubuntu~0.10.04.2_i306.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-gl-450_450.57-0ubuntu~0.10.04.2_amd64.deb
E: Subproccess /var/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

then i run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and it raised:

[image]

then i test `sudo apt remove --purge <package>` and raise error:

[image]

thanks for your helps!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve it after 3 days serching.
first i ran

`LC_MESSAGES=C dpkg-divert --list 'nvidia-340' | sed -nre 's/^diversion of (.) to ./\1/p' | xargs -rd'\n' -n1 -- sudo dpkg-divert --remove`

`sudo apt --fix-broken install`

then:

`sudo apt purge nvidia*`

and reboot.